# Trying to Understand class

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to understand the concept of class when I'm using db ,(mvc 3)
adding a class using the same name of any of  my db table always give me error saying 
Missing partial modifier on declaration of type MySite.Models.computers'; another partial declaration of this type exists, so how am I suppose to do it ?
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public  class computers 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // public IEnumerable<computers> computers { get; set; }
    // i would like to have this parameter a IEnumerable <price>
    // -in my db this is a string 
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Aron, I'm sorry to say it but I don't think this can be answered sufficiently here. I think you really need to go back to the ASP.NET MVC tutorials and better understand what you have implemented. It sounds as though you have already created classes relating to your database tables, perhaps through entity framework, and you need to be using those. Without you posting your project it's hard to know what you've done.

Comment: Lazarus , yes I do have EF on my project

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you already have a LinqToSql database context in your project.

changing

```
    public  class computers 
    {
...
    }
```

to

```
public partial class computers 
{
...
}
```

will let your project build, but without further information, it's hard to tell if that's really what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're using some kind of tool (Entity Framework, Linq-to-SQL, etc) that's generating a class for you.  It will be generated as a partial class like this:

```
public partial class computers { ... }
```

The reason it does this is that you might want to include some logic into that class.  So, the tool makes it `partial` and then you can define another `partial` class in the same folder.  The compiler will merge the two of them for you at build time.

However if you try to make another class in the same folder called computer without defining it as `partial`, it's an error.  You cannot have two classes with the same name in the same folder (namespace).  Two `partial` classes are find though, because they are really the same class after they're merged.

I doubt this is anything to do with MVC.